# IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'java.lang.String'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

I am working on an eCommerce web application in Spring Boot. I am facing an HTTP Status 500 error. Actually, I am trying to submit a form in which I am uploading a product image. All functions are working fine, but when I hit submit button, I get an internal server error with a message as below:

*2021-04-21 12:32:18.511  WARN 20042 --- [nio-9111-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'java.lang.String'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'java.lang.String': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]*

Below is my controller code for the upload file. In the below code, I have extracted the file name and its extension and then converted it into bytes.

```
@RequestMapping(value = ApiUrl.uploadfile, method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET }, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<?> uploadfile(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        CustomResponse = ResponseFactory.getResponse(request);
        String imgurl = "NA";
        try {
            String path = Constants.webmedia;
            String relativepath = "public/media/";
            System.out.println("Here is the image: ");
            if (null != file) {
                String filename = file.getOriginalFilename();
                String extension = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf("."), filename.length());
                System.out.println("filename : " + filename + " || extension : " + extension);
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
                Date date = new Date();
                String formatdate = format.format(date);
                formatdate = "imgurl" + formatdate;
                System.out.println("formatdate : " + formatdate);
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(path + File.separator + formatdate + extension)));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.flush();
                stream.close();
                imgurl = relativepath + formatdate + extension;
                System.out.println("imgurl : " + imgurl);
                if (imgurl != null) {
                    CustomResponse.setResponse(imgurl);
                    CustomResponse.setStatus(CustomStatus.OK);
                    CustomResponse.setStatusCode(CustomStatus.OK_CODE);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            CustomResponse.setResponse(null);
            CustomResponse.setStatus(CustomStatus.Error);
            CustomResponse.setStatusCode(CustomStatus.Error_CODE);
            CustomResponse.setResponseMessage(CustomStatus.ErrorMsg);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<ResponseDao>(CustomResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the Controller code?

Comment: Okay, I'll update my query.

Comment: Will it help when you add an appropiate content type to response?

Comment: Sorry, but I did not get your point.

Comment: Usual HTML form Submission or submission using REST API??

Comment: Usual form submission. I am not submitting the form using REST API.